# copy paste in textbox

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I was trying to copy numbers from excel and paste them in a matplotlib Textbox, which seems don't work with this comamnd. this what i try, any help?

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, TextBox

# Define a function to handle key press events
def on_key_press(event):
    # Check if the key pressed was Ctrl-V (paste)
    if event.key == "ctrl+v":
        # Get the clipboard content and set it as the text box value
        root = event.canvas.get_tk_widget().master
        clipboard_content = root.clipboard_get()
        event.inaxes.set_val(str(clipboard_content))

# Create the figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define the positions of the text boxes
positions = [(0.1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.05, "Title 1", "label1", "default1"),
             (0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.05, "Title 2", "label2", "default2"),
             (0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.05, "Title 3", "label3", "default3")]

# Create the text boxes and sliders
text_boxes = []
sliders = []
for x, y, w, h, title, label, default_text in positions:
    ax_box = fig.add_axes([x, y, w, h])
    text_box = TextBox(ax_box, title, initial=default_text)
    text_box.on_key_press_event = on_key_press # bind the on_key_press event
    text_boxes.append(text_box)

    ax_slider = fig.add_axes([x, y-0.1, w, 0.05])
    slider = Slider(ax_slider, label, 0, 1, valinit=float(default_text))
    sliders.append(slider)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, you need to provide more information of what you're asking and also provide enough code to reproduce your issue. Example: what is "plt" in your code above?  In the mean time, are you sure you're defining the event properly "ctrl+v" - maybe try '<ctrl-v>'.

Comment: You should use the [```connect_event()```](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.AxesWidget.connect_event) to bind. Also, you assumed you embedded a Matplotlib figure in Tkinter, but you didn't.